# Moment of a force convention?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, reference-frames, torque, statics, moment

> Two forces P and Q pass through a point A which is 4 m to the right of and 3 m above a moment center O. Force P is 890 N directed up to the right at 30° with the horizontal and force Q is 445 N directed up to the left at 60° with the horizontal. Determine the moment of the resultant of these two forces with respect to O.

**My question is**:  point O is the pivot point, right?

And the displacement vector (moment arm) is the vector joining point O to point A ?

In general when asked find the moment about point B, B is taken as the pivot point ?

Comment: This question needs a  picture, it would really improve your chances of an answer. Best of luck with it.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/d0vm2r

Comment: the question: what is  the moment about point A?

Comment: is the vector joining A to O ?

Comment: let me phrase it better:  If you say moment about A, you need to specify the distance where the force is acting , otherwise it would not make any sense ?

Answer (score 2):

> point O is the pivot point, right?

It is the rotation centre, yes.

> And the displacement vector (moment arm) is the vector joining point O to point A ?

Yes.

> In general when asked find the moment about point B, B is taken as the pivot point ?

You can calculate moments about *any* point. You would maybe only call it a "pivot" point, if something was actually moving around it, though.

Remember that nothing necessarily has to move for us to calculate moments. And the question doesn't say anything about pivots.

In general, you just need to know the **size** of the force, it's **direction** (so that you can take the perpendicular component only) and its **distance** $r$ to the rotation centre, where ever that might be. All neatly combined in this formula:
$$\tau=Fr$$

where $\tau$ is the moment and $F$ the force component perpendicular to the arm $r$.

Comment: sorry.,  what ? ?

Comment: But you need at least one pivot, which is usually the origin of coordinate system, right ?

Comment: @lohey Sorry of I wasn't clear enough. The answer is now extended a bit. But anyways, why do you need a pivot to calculate moments? As far as I'm aware a "pivot" point is just a mechanical term of a type of nonfixing joint. But moments work around other points that just joints.